# Product filter in category

Tags: product-list, filter

i want add filter how this:
http://flodomo.de/cat/index/sCategory/28
or 
http://flodomo.de/hochglanzlaminat
and etc.. because it is necessary that each category included a specific set of data filtering, let me know how i can to in magento, may be an appropriate extension that can be used.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento already has a filtering system.
You just have to configure your filtrable attributes in the backend and set the flag `is anchor` to `true` for your categories.
When you are done rebuild your indexes.
The only problem is that the filters appear on the left side.
You can either try to move them in the center part of the page and adjust the markup and style yo fit your needs or your can use [this extension](http://www.manadev.com/seo-layered-navigation-plus).  Among other cool features it allows you to move the filters on the center part of the page.

Comment: ie I can use a variety of filter options for each category?

Comment: The filters are determined automatically based on the products in your category. So yes...different types of products will show different filters